# How to update WINEPREFIX without starting an app

Tags: linux, wine

When wine package is updated on the system most `WINEPREFIX`'es (unless configured to use a specific version of wine) needs to be updated as well. As far as everybody knows the update is handled automatically when an app is started against the prefix. So something like `WINEPREFIX='/path/to/prefix' winecfg` would be sufficient.

However I'm looking for a way to do a bulk update of several prefixes without user input. And preferably without the X running. Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to run a non graphical wine/windows command and not set `$DISPLAY` at all.

here's an example:

```
$ unset DISPLAY
$ wine ping
000b:fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 3.21 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
000b:fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0027:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0027:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0027:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0027:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
002b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
002b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0027:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error -536870654
002d:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
002d:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
0027:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0027:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error -536870654
0027:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0027:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error -536870654
wine: configuration in '/home/test/.wine' has been updated.
Usage: ping [-n count] [-w timeout] [-l buffer_length] target_name

Options:
    -n  Number of echo requests to send.
    -w  Timeout in milliseconds to wait for each reply.
    -l  Length of send buffer.
```

Normally there would have been popups asking to download mono and wine-gecko. Those parts failed (if needed they can be made available beforehand afaik), but the upgrade was made anyway as you can see:

```
wine: configuration in '/home/test/.wine' has been updated.
```

(And the ping command complained of the syntax: it actually ran).

Of course, there's no guarantee that this behaviour will stay the same. So you should do tests and backups.

EDIT: as asked, for a more neutral command and output:

```
unset DISPLAY
export WINEDEBUG=-all
wine net help >/dev/null
```

will yield only two lines (or possibly only the last) to *stderr* and give exit code 0:

```
Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: configuration in '/home/test/.wine' has been updated.
```

Comment: I've found nothing better either... any suggestions is there a better candidate for the application? e.g. with no output and zero return code in case no errors occurred?

Answer (score 0):

Completely automatic, no question asked during update:

```
for I in */wine*
do
    WINEDLLOVERRIDES="winemenubuilder.exe=d;mscoree=d;" WINEPREFIX="$PWD/$I" wineboot --update
done
```

Description:

- `for I in */wine*` - enumerates all your wineprefixes
- `WINEDLLOVERRIDES="winemenubuilder.exe=d;mscoree=d;"` - do not update desktop shortcuts and never ask to update mono
- `wineboot --update` - the update of prefix